# How to remove slug metabox from custom post type's page?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I just discovered a new meta field on the newly created custom post type page. The meta name is slug, and it's under the wp editor field. What's that, and how can I remove it?

Answer (score 5):

You can remove the slug metabox from a post type with remove_meta_box:

```
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'my_add_meta_boxes' );
function my_add_meta_boxes() {
    remove_meta_box( 'slugdiv', 'my_post_type', 'normal' );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but why does it have a new metabox? I also can edit the url under the title, whats the difference?

Comment: Be warned that this seems to break the slug editing functionality under the post title.  https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18523

Answer (score 2):

on the top right of the page where you edit your post or page you will see two buttons:
[Screen options] and [Help].
Click on [screen options]. You will see all kinds of options, unmark the one labeled "Slug" and it will disappear from the post/page edit page.

If you want to know what that was: http://codex.wordpress.org/Glossary#Post_Slug

Hope that helps